# simple bash script with if else statement plus debugging issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm working on a simple bash script and no matter what the user inputs as `choice`, the result of the first condition is always printed.  Can someone explain what's going on here?  On side note, how do you go about debugging a bash script like this?  When I try debugging in ecplise using the shell script plugin, the only option is an "ant build" which, when I try it, does nothing arrgggh!

```
if [ -f $1 ]
then
    echo "Are you sure you want to delete $1? Y for yes, N for no"
    read choice
    if [ $choice="Y" ]
    then
        echo "okay"
    else
        echo "file was not deleted"
    fi 
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ $choice="Y" ]` Replaces `$choice`, then sees if the replacement with '="Y"' appended to it is a non-empty string. You meant `[ "$choice" = Y ]`.

Comment: That works for the conditional statement.  However, Y is then assigned to the choice variable which is something I don't want.  How do I avoid that?

Comment: @ignacio --  when I first read that, I was parsing that as "Replacing $choice with "Y"... which isn't possible because $choice is an rvalue. Reading it again, I see that you mean 'Replaces $choice with its value', and the value is interpreted as a variable which is assigned the value "Y". After all is said and done, $choice remains equal to 'N', and $N is equal to 'Y'.

Comment: It does not replace 'choice'.  It tests whether the string "$choice=Y" is nonempty.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:  So what is another way to do what I want without using read.  i.e. I want to compare the value of variable `choice` with the string "Y" but I don't want to change the value of `choice`.

Answer (score 0):

If think you launch your script without any argument.
In that case $1 refers to nothing and `[ -f $1 ]` is always true.
Try to launch your script with an argument to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to track the execution of your script use

```
set -x
```

This will make the shell print out the values as the interpreter sees them, line by line... however, in this case, it doesn't tell you very much:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.sh 
set -x
if [ -f $1 ]
then
    echo "Are you sure you want to delete $1? Y for yes, N for no"
    read choice
    if [ $choice="Y" ]
    then
        echo "okay"
    else
        echo "file was not deleted"
    fi 
fi



$ bash /tmp/test.sh 
+ '[' -f ']'
+ echo 'Are you sure you want to delete ? Y for yes, N for no'
Are you sure you want to delete ? Y for yes, N for no
+ read choice
N
+ '[' N=Y ']'
+ echo okay
okay
```

Well... actually, it literally tells you that '[ $choice="Y" ]' is incorrect, but it doesn't tell you why it's wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: As Ignacio told, when `[` has only zero/one argument, it treats it as a string, which is true if it's not empty. So `+ '[' N=Y ']'` is basically showing a test for the emptyness of the `N=Y` string.